# Multi select Dropdown with filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement where in I have to create a multi select drop down where the elements can be searchable and the count of selected items should be displayed upon selection.

I have found the partial part of the requirements at this [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Tiny-Two-Panel-Multi-Selection-Plugin-jQuery-multi-js/)

But not sure how to make the drop down collapsible and expandable

Wire frame image as below

Has anyone come across and worked on such requirements?

Comment: share your code what you have tried so for!

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends also a bit if you are using plain Javascript or if you are also using a Framework like Angular/vue/ember or so

here is one component that looks like it makes what you want

http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: Thanks for your response CodeHacker! Earlier I was using Chosen Plugin to achieve my requirements, where the user selects the dropdown and upon selection the elements gets added . [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/iamravikk/Legxf0vk)

I want to use either plain Javascript or Jquery or any other framwork which achieves that

Comment: Well selectize is jQuery based... if you look at the max-items sample it also works like a tagger. And in the "plugins"-tab, you'll find also with "remove_button"